# How to remove orange outline/border from input/textarea on Android with TouchWiz

Tags: android, css, cordova, user-interface

I have input styled like holo theme by CSS but on focus appears orange outline and white background.

I found solution to remove this:

```
textarea:focus{
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```

But this solution causing that the text inside field is not visible while typing (except first letter). Text shows up after leaving the focus.

Another soulution like that:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

doesn't work...

More solutions?

Tested on Android 4.0.1 (Samsung Galaxy SII).

Answer (score 2):

To remove the outline of a textarea try with:

```
:focus {
  outline: none; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Hope it helps!